# where to get address like 10.0.2.0 in android?

Tags: ip

I am trying to get IP address of Android Phone and it shows something like 192.168.0.0.But i need some thing like 10.0.2.0.Are both same?.Can anyone tell me what is the difference and How to get that address?

Thank you

Comment: Your question makes very little sense.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address#Private_addresses

Comment: @zerkms I need that address in VpnService class of Android.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AVD?

The AVD receives its network address and configuration on the private network from a DHCP server that is integrated into Virtual. The address which the virtual Device receives is usually on a completely different network to the host. As more than one card of a virtual device can be set up to use NAT networking, the first card is connected to the private network 10.0.2.0, the second card to the network 10.0.3.0 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It is highly unlikely that you have an IP with a 0 at the end because they are mostly used as the Network ID, especially with the 192.168.0.0 adress. The 10.0.2.0 and the 192.168.0.0 Adress are both IP Adresses that are in the private Range, so they are not public. I assume that you get your IP via DHCP so it depends on that DHCP Server what IP you will get. In the end of the day it doesn't really matter if you have an 10.0.xx.xx or a 192.168.0.xx Adress. Maybe I could help you a little more if you tell me why you need a 10.0.2.0 adress?

Comment: I need that address for Vpnservice class.I am trying to connect using Builder.addAddress(10.0.2.0,24);

Answer (score 0):

10.0.0.2 is an IP address found on many local computer networks, particularly business networks.Internet Protocol (IP) version 4 defines certain sets of IP addresses as restricted for private use (not available to be assigned to Web servers or other Internet hosts).